# Apache POI: How to set font style for a field (PAGE, PAGENUM, PAGEREF...)

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

From another (answered) question I learned how to add a page counter into a Word document. In addition I need to set the font family style (color, bold, italic, underline...) on the field (i.e. page counter). How can this be achieved?

```
CTSimpleField ctSimpleField = paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
```

CTSimpleField does not provide methods to directly set these attributes.

Original question: [How to add page numbers in format X of Y while creating a word document using apache poi api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385707/how-to-add-page-numbers-in-format-x-of-y-while-creating-a-word-document-using-ap)

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 1");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 2");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 3");

  // create header-footer
  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = doc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
  if (headerFooterPolicy == null) headerFooterPolicy = doc.createHeaderFooterPolicy();

  // create header start
  XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Header:");

  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Page ");
  // this adds the page counter
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE \\* MERGEFORMAT");
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText(" of ");
  // this adds the page total number
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("NUMPAGES \\* MERGEFORMAT");

  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeaderFooter.docx"));

 }
}
```

Comment: Formatting "Page x of y" only formats "Page" and "of", but not x or y.<br/>
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
    run.setText("Page ");  
    run.setBold(true);  
    run.setFontFamily("Arial");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to formatting, we need runs in `Word`. But to create fields using runs we need three runs for each field. One run to mark the `FldChar` start, then one run to mark the fields `InstrText` and the third run to mark the `FldChar` end. And each run can, but also must, be formatted as needed.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 1");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 2");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 3");

  // create header-footer
  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = doc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
  if (headerFooterPolicy == null) headerFooterPolicy = doc.createHeaderFooterPolicy();

  // create header start
  XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Header:");

  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setBold(true);  
  run.setText("Page ");

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setBold(true); 
  run.getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STFldCharType.BEGIN);

  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setBold(true); 
  run.getCTR().addNewInstrText().setStringValue("PAGE \\* MERGEFORMAT");

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setBold(true); 
  run.getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STFldCharType.END);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setBold(true); 
  run.setText(" of ");

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setBold(true); 
  run.getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STFldCharType.BEGIN);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setBold(true); 
  run.getCTR().addNewInstrText().setStringValue("NUMPAGES \\* MERGEFORMAT");

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setBold(true); 
  run.getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STFldCharType.END);

  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeaderFooter.docx"));

 }
}
```